# Can't alter admin user password for PostgreSQL in Docker

Tags: postgresql, nginx, docker

I'm working into a Docker container for some study, using nginx + php + postrgresql, and some ssh to connect with host.

Problem is that I can't exchange the container's PostgreSQL admin password (for internal, not filesystem).

I've based my Dockerfile into some I've investigated and looked like what I wanted.

The Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/fabiocosta0305/docker-lamp/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Either tried with lines 84-85 and using the same lines at an script called at lines 80-82. Either option, I receive the same error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer you're looking for but ideally you would run your database in a separate container and have the app container running httpd and your php code linked to it using docker-compose.  The [official postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) exposes an env var to set the admin password, POSTGRES_PASSWORD.

I've found that using official images for things like databases saves alot of time and headache as the teams producing them add easy-to-use features to get you off the ground quickly, such as env vars to set db passwords.

The docker team has a good tutorial for wordpress using mysql that should point you in the right direction regarding a docker-compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/

```
version: '2'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```